# Powershell set field value based on folder name

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, script

I need to find a way using Powershell to set the value of a field in a document library based on a folder name. So for example if there is a folder called "00170" and there is a field named "Reference", I would like the value of "00170" set to this field.

I have little to none scripting skills so would appreciate some help with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use PowerShell.

Do you want to set the field in this folder to the folder name? If so, you can go to library settings > Column default value settings, select your folder under "Location to configure" section.
[image]
Then click the "reference" field and set a default value for this field.
[image]
If you want to grant the folder name to the reference column of this folder, you can create a workflow to achieve your purpose. Just using "Update list Item" action in the workflow to grant the folder name to the reference column of current item.
[image]

Comment: Thank you imp. MSFT. I got it but what if you have hundreds of folders to do this Job? Please suggest. Thank you in advance.